# Paginated stats report

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a simple messaging system using MySQL. So I have a table structure like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` blob,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Now, I'm working on some god panel stats that should present a paginated, sortable by columns table report with this columns:

User ID, Full Name & Email (separate table)
Messages sent yesterday
Messages sent in the last 30 days
Messages sent lifetime

So I created a `messages_stats_daily` table like this, that a nightly process fills up every night with "yesterday's" data:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages_stats_daily` (
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`user_id`)
)
```

So this is the query I'm using for the report:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.*, msd1.count, SUM(msd_30days.count), SUM(msd3.count) 
FROM accounts a 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON a.default_user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN messages_stats_daily msd_yesterday 
  ON u.account_id = msd_yesterday.account_id 
    AND msd_yesterday.date = date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
LEFT JOIN messages_stats_daily msd_30days 
  ON u.account_id = msd_30days.account_id 
    AND (msd_30days.date BETWEEN date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND CURDATE())
LEFT JOIN messages_stats_daily msd_lifetime 
  ON u.account_id = msd_lifetime.account_id
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY SUM(msd_30days.count)
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

But for some reason, the numbers are wrong. They get weirdly multiplied but I couldn't determine a fixed factor (I know they are multiplied because the aprox. relations between 1 day, 30 days and 2 years still apply). Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? I'm also open to change the stats nightly process behavior.

NOTE: I know I could do this by just getting the ID's from a first simple query and then firing three simple queries for these ID's, but this won't work since the report needs to be paginated and sortable by column.

Comment: I thought about adding two steps into the nightly process, so it fills two extra tables `messages_stats_30days` and `messages_stats_lifetime` so I could avoid the grouping. But I wanted to be sure this is the wisest.

Answer (score 0):

To paginate SQL results you use `LIMIT x, y` where x is the starting result (0-index) and y is the number of results. I can't see LIMIT anywhere in your query, so it's likely your overcomplicating your pagination.

Read more about it [here](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

---

I also noticed you aren't using the `AS` keyword when assigning aliases to your tables in the `LEFT JOIN` 's

Read more about aliases [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

---

As you mentioned doing 3 separate queries, you could look into doing nested/sub queries. To save actually submitting multiple queries. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)

Comment: Oh, I intentionally removed the LIMIT and ORDER BY parts of the query because they are not relevant to my issue (and forgot the GROUP BY part, which I now added). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, if they aren't relevant the use of pagination all through your post and title was unnecessary.

Comment: The fact that I need pagination & sorting is relevant to the fact that I need one and only one SQL statement (or other trick that someone might have).

Comment: Also, from the MySQL manual "A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: But you removed the pagination part from your existing SQL statement you provided us with! About the aliases, my bad, I just saw inconsistency there.

Comment: I did so because the numbers still show up incorrectly with no `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` parts and for the sake of simplicity, but just edited the query to include them.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the thing by separating the grouping into subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT u.*, msd_yesterday.count, msd_30days.count, msd_lifetime.count
FROM accounts a 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON a.default_user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_id, count FROM messages_stats_daily WHERE date = date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY account_id) msd_yesterday 
  ON u.account_id = msd_yesterday.account_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_id, sum(count) AS count FROM messages_stats_daily WHERE date BETWEEN date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY account_id) msd_30days 
  ON u.account_id = msd_30days.account_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_id, sum(count) AS count FROM messages_stats_daily GROUP BY account_id) msd_lifetime 
  ON u.account_id = msd_lifetime.account_id
GROUP BY `a`.`id`;
```